# GC Overhead Limit Exceeded for Large CSV Reads in Scala

Tags: scala, garbage-collection, jvm, sbt

So. I'm using Scala, and I'm relatively new to it (mostly a python guy). I'm compiling and running my code via sbt. I'm on an Ubuntu box, currently running Java 6. I have two CSVs; I need to take them, process them, then manipulate them. Each CSV is ~250mb; if this works I'm likely to repeat this process with much larger CSVs.

I've defined a function that reads in a CSV and writes each row into the data structure I need. I call this function on each CSV in series. Problem is: it returns perfectly (and very quickly) for the first CSV, but the second one always throws a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded` error.

I've tried rather a number of things. My `build.sbt` defines `javaOptions += "-Xmx20480m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError"`; I've tried using `-XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit` as well, but that doesn't seem to help anything. According to the Java docs I've been reading, that error indicates that a huge amount of system resource is being spent on garbage collection -- but I'm frankly unclear what it's garbage collecting, or how to trim it down. I assume my function must be... leaking memory somewhere, or I must be mis-using Scala, but I can't see how.

Here's my function:

```
def readAndProcessData(path: String) = {
    val fileLines = Source.fromFile(path).getLines.drop(1)
    val ret = mutable.Map[String, List[Tuple2[String, String]]]()

    def addRowToRet(row: String) = {
        val rowArray = row.split(",")
        if (!(ret contains rowArray(0))) {
            ret.update(rowArray(0), List[Tuple2[String, String]]())
        }
        ret(rowArray(0)) = Tuple2(rowArray(1), rowArray(2)) :: ret(rowArray(0))
    }

    for (row <- fileLines) {
        addRowToRet(row)
    }

    ret.map{tup => (tup._1 -> tup._2.sorted)}

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: using for loop doesnt look Scala'ish.                               1. use filelines.foldLeft to transform the csv data in to map.       2. try to make addRowtoRet recursive

Comment: if u still want to go with the same code try using ret.par.map{tup => (tup._1 -> tup._2.sorted)}

Comment: Are you Forking when running in sbt?  javaOptions is only used for if sbt forks a new process to run your program, which is not the default behavior.

Comment: @Rajesh -- yeah, the for loop is displeasing; I've been trying to figure out how to remove it. Thanks for the foldLeft suggestion -- will look in to that! And I hadn't considered parallelizing the sort, but that's not the step the thing is choking on the second time through, alas. Thanks!

Comment: @ErikEngbrecht oh man, I did not know that about SBT. I am going to go read up on Forking right now -- that would explain a *lot* of stuff.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, if you're not forking to run, either [enable forking](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Forking) or up the memory limit for sbt and remove the javaOptions setting.  Forking may be a good idea here so you are not intermixing the memory usage behavior of your program with that of sbt.

You also should close the Source object you are creating to make sure its resources are released.

Is it crashing in a consistent place, e.g. when sorting?  Or does the crash occur at pretty random spots in the code?

I assume that the files you are reading are in an encoding such as ASCII or UTF8 where most to all of the characters are represented with 8 bits.  Java uses 16 bits per character, so keep in mind that you are more than doubling the size (the "more than" is due to other overheads) by reading it into Java strings.  That in itself shouldn't push you over, but it means by the time you have two 250MB files loaded you'll probably be consuming more than 1GB of memory for the data.

How distributed are your keys relative to the number of lines in your files?  In other words, is there an entry in your map for almost every line, for about half the lines, a quarter, etc?  You potentially could have a pretty big map (in terms of entries) and when you perform the "map" operating on it to sort the values you'll end up with two of them in memory until the function returns and the old one becomes collectible.  You also might want to try using an immutable map or a wrapper around a Java mutable map.  Sometimes Scala's mutable data structures aren't as robust as their immutable counterparts.

Also, I've never had good luck with scala.io.Source.  If it's still failing once you're fairly certain you actually have enough memory allocated, you might want to try dropping down to using Java's IO libraries.

Finally, if checking a few settings and poking at it a bit doesn't work, you should hook up a memory profiler to it such as [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/).  That was you have a shot at figuring out where your problem really is rather than doing guess-and-check with modifications.

Comment: your suggestion to enable forking seems to have basically instantly resolved the problem! Thank you so much for your time in this -- you've given me a lot of other really good information too, which is classy as hell. So far, enabling forking in my run has resolved everything -- brilliant!

Answer (score 0):

try returning the ret and map it in a wrapping method. That should avoid having everything local in memory.